# Sorting an Array - C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Below is a for loop that I have created. It reads in the red pixel from each image and calculates the mean of all of them using a separate function. For another algorithm I need to caluclate the median. In order to calculate the median I need to sort the values from lowest to highest which is what I am having problems with. I cant get the sort function that is built in to work too. Any advice / help on where to go with this?

Update1: Updated code to get the median working. Thanks! 
I have output the values and they are correct. The problem now is that it takes a while. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Thanks

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 7990272; i++)
    {
        std::vector<float> v{ img1->pixels[i].r + img2->pixels[i].r + img3->pixels[i].r + img4->pixels[i].r + img5->pixels[i].r + img6->pixels[i].r + img7->pixels[i].r + img8->pixels[i].r + img9->pixels[i].r + img10->pixels[i].r + img11->pixels[i].r + img12->pixels[i].r + img13->pixels[i].r };
        std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size() / 2, v.end());
        //std::cout << "The median is " << (v[v.size() / 2]) / 13 << '\n';   <--- proof the median works
        newimage->pixels[i].r = ((v[v.size() / 2])/13);

    }   

    writePPM(*newimage, "testPPM.ppm");
```

Comment: C++ has a [standard algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) for that. Note that selection doesn't require sorting.

Comment: You can use [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) for finding median.

Comment: is that method not for vectors only?

Comment: @Russsu No, why do you think that it is? If it was meant for `vector`s only, it wouldn't make sense declaring it in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Your code to create `redarr` makes no sense whatsoever. Once you fix that you may have better luck applying the other advice.

Comment: Updated my code. Median working after changing around. Problem is time. takes a while to work

Comment: Why not store the images in a `vector`?

Comment: 13 different images with 7 million pixels per image. Would it be possible? And would it speed up the process?

Comment: Is that your real code? You create a 1 element vector almost 8 million times, try to get the nth element which is pointless because the size is 1, and basically take the average of the numbers you used to construct the single element vector. Are your pixel values really floats?

Comment: yeah they are floats. How would you go about this then?

Comment: Adding up 13 numbers and taking the average? First I wouldn't have 13 different named image pointers. Use an array or a vector, then just do the math for the average. If you actually do want the median then add the individual elements to a vector or array and use nth element. You should get rid of the magic numbers too. I'm also going to guess it takes a long time because you're not building with optimizations on.

Comment: A potential bottleneck could also be img->pixels[i].r if this actually makes a function call. If you have access to the buffer holding the pixels, retrieving the red component for every pixel manually is trivial and usually much faster than using APIs.